# $ \int_{E} |f|d\mu \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2} \int_{E}f^21_{\{|f|\leq n\}}d\mu} $

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal {A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space.

Let $f:(E,\mathcal{A}))\to (\mathbb {R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) $ be a measurable function.

Show that :
$$
\int_{E} |f|d\mu <\infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2} \int_{E}f^21_{\{|f|\leq n\}}d\mu} <\infty
$$

My first step of demo is :

we have :
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2} \int_{E}f^2 1_{\{|f|\leq n\}}d\mu} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2} \int_{E}f^2 1_{\biguplus_{k=0}^{n-1}\{k<|f|\leq k+1\}}d\mu} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{E}f^2 1_{\{k<|f|\leq k+1\}}d\mu} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \left(\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}\right) \left(\int_{E}f^2 1_{\{k<|f|\leq k+1\}}d\mu\right)
$$

but i can't continue, an idea please

Comment: What do mean by show that? You have two expressions, not statements.

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: Do you mean to say one is finite **iff**  the other is, perhaps?

Comment: Presumably the question at hand is to show that $f\in L^1$ if and only if the right-hand side of the "$\iff$" is finite?

Comment: yes, i forgot to write infinity. thank you

Answer (score 2):

There exist constants $c>0$, $C>0$ such that

$$c \frac{1}{k} \leq \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \leq C \frac{1}{k}$$

for large $k \gg 1$ (use e.g. integral comparison). By the calculation from your question, this implies

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \int f^2 1_{|f| \leq n} \, d\mu < \infty \iff \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \int f^2 1_{k<|f| \leq k+1} \, d\mu < \infty. $$

Consequently, it suffices to show

$$\int |f| \, d\mu < \infty \iff \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \int f^2 1_{k<|f| \leq k+1} \, d\mu < \infty. \tag{1}$$

If $f \in L^1(\mu)$, then

\begin{align*} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \int f^2 1_{k<|f| \leq k+1} \, d\mu &\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k+1}{k} \int |f| 1_{k<|f| \leq k+1} \, d\mu \\ &\leq 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int |f| 1_{k<|f| \leq k+1} \, d\mu \\ &\leq 2 \int |f| \, d\mu < \infty. \end{align*}

On the other hand,

\begin{align*} \int |f| \, d\mu &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int |f| 1_{k <|f| \leq k+1} \, d\mu \\ &\leq \mu(E) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int |f| 1_{k <|f| \leq k+1} \, d\mu  \\ &\leq \mu(E) +  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int |f| \frac{|f|}{k} 1_{k <|f| \leq k+1} \, d\mu \\ &= \mu(E) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \int f^2 1_{k<|f| \leq k+1} \ d\mu, \end{align*}

and so

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \int f^2 1_{k<|f| \leq k+1} \, d\mu < \infty \implies \int |f| \, d\mu < \infty.$$

Comment: @Masacroso Sorry, I don't see your point. There are non-negative functions such that the integral over any bounded interval is infinite, yes... but why is this a contradiction to the OP's assertion?